# Crash in uiautomationcore.dll

Tags: .net, ui-automation

After upgrading our Windows VDI to Win10 21H2, we are encountering sporadic but persistent crashes in UIAutomationcore.dll:

SYMBOL_NAME:  uiautomationcore!BlockingCoreDispatcher::CreateAndRegisterBlockingCore+98

MODULE_NAME: uiautomationcore

IMAGE_NAME:  uiautomationcore.dll

STACK_COMMAND:  ~39s; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_c0000005_uiautomationcore.dll!BlockingCoreDispatcher::CreateAndRegisterBlockingCore

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  7.2.19041.1741

Has anyone else run into this? Any suggested solution?

We have tried to troubleshoot this issue for the past two days. It is occurring when an old application invokes this DLL so it appears to have been introduced by the Windows update.